# Как правильно cделать вопрос в консоли и считать ответ (Y/N)

Tags: c, консоль

Как правильно в консоли сделать вопрос с помощью C и получить ответ (Y/N).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ideone.com/tGWIV2

Считывает всё до первого из символов `YyNn` и его. Если конец файла будет достигнут раньше, то вернёт 0 (no).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int confirm(const char *msg)
  {
  int ch;   

  puts(msg);
  scanf("%*[^YyNn]");
  ch = getchar();

  return ch=='Y' || ch=='y';
  }

int main(void)
  {
  char s[256];

  puts(confirm("Enter Y or N") ? "You've selected [yes]" : "You've selected [no]");
  puts(gets(s));

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Вышеприведенная реализация содержит распространенную грубую ошибку: чтобы принимать результат функции `getchar()`  нажна переменная типа `int`, а не `char`. Значение `EOF`, которое потенциально может вернуть функция `getchar()`, не гарантированно попадает в диапазон типа `char`. Именно для того, чтобы `getchar()` могла вернуть `EOF`, ее тип возврата сделан `int`. По этой причине нельзя утверждать, что функция `confirm` вернет `0` при достижении конца файла. Поведение вышеприведенного кода в случае достижения конца файла *в общем случае не определено*.

Comment: @AnT, `EOF` - это `-1`. Да, в char он не совсем влазиет (и я об этом в курсе), но ни одна из букв `Yy` не имеет не только кода -1 или 255, но и никакого отрицательного кода, поэтому возвращено будет 0.

Comment: Нет, `EOF` - это некое значение, определяемое реализацией, а не `-1`. `-1` - это лишь частный пример возможного значени `EOF`. Потому и я говорю, что оно не гарантированно попадает в диапазон `char`.

Comment: @AnT, и где конкретно оно не `-1`? Кстати, -1 - это тоже не совсем char. Для всех 256 char'овских кодов есть символы. А это интовая -1, которая как бы вне остальных значений - они однобайтовые. Впрочем ладно, поменял char на int.

Answer (score 0):

printf() для текста вопроса и getch() для получения нажатой клавиши. Но это не "правильно", а просто рабочий вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char get_ans(unsigned char default = 1) {
    switch(getchar()) {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            return 1;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            return 0;
        case EOF:
            return EOF;
    }
    return default;
}
```

Куда уж проще.